# How come when I generate a signed APK it produces out a JKS file?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm using the newest version of Android Studio and I am looking at publishing an app on the Play store. Unfortunately when I generate a signed APK it only gives me the open to produce a JKS file. All the tutorials I've seen makes it look like you put an APK and that's what you get out, but those are using older versions of Android studio. Do I need to put the JKS file through something else, download an older version of Android Studio or am I missing a step? I'm really new at this and I'd appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a JKS file once. After that make sure You have something like this in Your gradle file, inside "android" part:

```
signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'key'
            keyPassword '123456'
            storeFile file('../app/key/yourAppKey.jks')
            storePassword '123456'
        }
}
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config

        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config

    }
}
```

After this part has been added just set build variant -> release and then use build -> build bundle/apk -> build apk

Comment: hi, do I need to import this as a separate gradle or can I add this to one of the existing gradles? if so, which one, the 'mobile' one or the 'app' one?

Comment: Add this to the "app" level gradle.